# Why does the upper right corner give the determinant for matrices of this form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking at [these notes](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Ejvondrak/MATH233B-2017/lec3.pdf) about totally unimodular matrices. For Lemma 4 it is stated that

> *Lemma 4* If A is totally unimodular, then $\begin{pmatrix} 
> A \\
> I
> \end{pmatrix}$
> is totally unimodular.

The proof is stated as follows:

> By the determinant expansion formula, the determinant of any square submatrix $A'$ is
> equal to $0$ or $\pm \det A''$ where $A''$ is a square submatrix of $A$ (see the figure). By definition, $\det A'' \in \{0, \pm1\}$.

Referring to the figure, $A'$ is of the form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
B_1 & A'' \\
I_k & B_2
\end{pmatrix}$$

What I do not understand is how $B_1$ and $B_2$ do not play any role in the determinant. I am probably missing something simple but it seems like even with Laplace expansion that $B_1$ and $B_2$ should be used in the calculation and that the determinant is not solely determined as either $0$ or by $\det A''$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3767701/15140) also seems to suggest expansion, but I do not follow what $B''$, $B'''$ etc. are and how they correspond to the rank of $I$.